# How do I index a four-dimensional array using a two-dimensional boolean?

Tags: python, arrays, indexing, boolean

I have an four-dimensional array (10x9x1154x40). I want to index the array using a boolean matrix which relates to the last two dimensions (1154x40).

I have tried this:

```
x = 4dArray[:,:,boolMatrix]
```

however this given me a three dimensional array (10x9x948).

How can I use the boolean matrix to index across the final two dimensions, keeping the number of dimensions the same?